# How to change the Y-Axis in Plotly to go from scientific to exponential or plain?

Tags: python, plotly, ohlc, iplots

Ive seen many different answers, but need one specifically for the use of Plotly in Python....my code is below, but the Y axis doesn't come back in basic decimal points (I believe it come back in some micro format where instead of .000258 it will show 258.XXX)

```
 floki_ohlc = df.iplot(kind = "ohlc",fill = True, colorscale = "rdylbu", theme = "solar",
                  title = "FLOKI INU/USDT", xTitle = "Time", yTitle = "Price (USD)")
```

And I cant find anything in the documentation about changing the values, only the titles.

Thanks in advance@

Comment: Update: Can actually be changed in Plolty Chart Studio but would still love to see if it can be done prior in the notebook before exporting

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using express. I used the diamonds dataset from the R  library ggplot2 for the plot.

It can be done in Python when you create the graph. Since I don't have your data, I've made a few examples and what changes and how it changes when I use it.

Plotly formatting uses D3. You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format).

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

diam_py = r.diamonds

df = pd.DataFrame(diam_py)

fig = df.plot.bar(x = "color", 
                  y = "price", 
                  color = "cut",
                  template = "simple_white",
                  barmode = "group")
fig.show()

fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=",.0f").show() # use thousand comma; round to whole number
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat="none").show() # show number as is
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=",.0s").show() # SI prefix with 0 significant digits
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat="#x").show()   # prefixed lowercase hexidecimal 
# more details at https://github.com/d3/d3-format
```

> The figures are in the order in which they appear in the code.

### Default y-axis formatting

[image: default]

### Use commas at the thousands & round to the whole number

[image: Big mark and rounded]

### Remove all formatting—show as is in the data

[image: No formatting]

### SI prefix with no significant digits (M for millions here)

[image: SI prefix, with no significant digits]

### Hexidecimal formatting...in case binary is of interest

[image: hexidecimal]

Comment: The link to the D3 format was in particular helpful.